# When display component reportdetails it display below menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular7, angular-components

problem

second component - table html display below menu but i need it display on right of menu .

I work on angular 7 and I have two components

first component is report component contain on left side menu and it is be router outlet on app.component

second component is table html exist on reportdetails component and generated when click link menu .

first component report contain menu

```
<p>report-category works!</p>

<table *ngFor="let rep of reportlist">  

     <tr>



            <td>{{rep.reportCategory}}</td>       

    </tr>

    <tr *ngFor="let subrep of subreportlist">

        <div *ngIf="subrep.reportCategoryID === rep.reportCategoryID">



                <a href="/reportdetails?id={{subrep.reportID}}">



                        <i class="{{subrep.IconClass}}"></i>

                        <span class="title">{{subrep.reportName}}</span>

                    </a>

        </div>



       </tr>



</table>
```

second is report component contain table that display below menu and this is wrong

the correct i need is to display right of menu as picture below

```
reportdetails works!

 <p>reportdetails works!</p>

  <div>
<table class="table table-hover" >  
  <thead>  
    <tr>  

      <th>regulation</th>  
    </tr>  
  </thead>  
  <tbody>  
      <tr *ngFor="let rep of reportdetailslist">
        <td>{{rep.regulation}}</td>  
      </tr>



  </tbody>  
</table>  
<p>reportdetails works!</p>

      <div>

    <table class="table table-hover" >  

      <thead>  

        <tr>  



          <th>regulation</th>  

        </tr>  

      </thead>  

      <tbody>  

          <tr *ngFor="let rep of reportdetailslist">

            <td>{{rep.regulation}}</td>  

          </tr>



      </tbody>  

    </table>  

  </div>
```

fiddle link as below :
https://jsfiddle.net/015asjzv/1/

what I try

```
table{
float:right;
width:auto;
}
```

Last Updated
see link here

http://www.mediafire.com/view/wnptffqakjglkre/correctdata.png/file

it moved table from left to right but i need it top beside menu so what i do
[image]

Comment: Can you add a working fiddle, please.

Comment: thank you for reply how to put on fiddle it is angular inside it

Comment: you can create a working demo on `stackblitz` or `codesandbox` both support angular

Comment: i updated post with fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/015asjzv/1/

Comment: can any one help me please

Comment: The code is not working in the fiddle, you can do one thing just add HTML and CSS part so that I can debug and please explain clearly your requirement.

Comment: The requirement seems to be unclear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213049/discussion-between-abhisar-tripathi-and-ahmed-barbary).

Comment: I need to display table beside vertical menu so in design

Comment: i will see menu on left as above no need any changes only i need table below menu display beside menu on empty space on right

Comment: meaning i need to make table css float :right then top to be level of menu

Comment: are there are any thing not clear

Comment: final design i need vertical menu on left not change - small space - table on right side meaning it start from left to right

Comment: if you see image above on rectangle red i need table start from left to right as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for what I can see at the moment u have 2 tables wrapped by divs that's why they show as block(divs have display: block; by default)

add another div around these 2

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  // You have to make sure only this divs are direct child of wrapper.
  // div table 1  || you can just remove the div and add table directly
  // div table 2  || as divs with no class dont add any value
</div>
// css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

Good luck.

You can learn more of display flex [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Note: This could also be an issue of the parent component layout, but the fix would be the same.